# Can I use the Option() constructor if I get the data from PHP on load?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Seeing other posts here, I now understand that I should not use html to build `<select>` input elements.

What I mean is that until now I was receiving the list of `options` from the server and I was building them using PHP echo (Laravel Blade syntax):

```
<select>
   @foreach($data as $row)
      <option value="{{ $row->value }}">{{ $row->value }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

But that caused issues because the values I receive from the server may include single or double quotes and it breaks everything.

Then I saw I should probably use something like the `Option()` constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

But until now I was returning the data from the server when the page was loaded, so I do not have the list of `options` stored in the frontend.

then should I use AJAX to call the list of options every time the page loads instead of getting it from the backend with PHP on load? Or there is another way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you replace the quotes with single quotes or ticks?

Comment: `<option value="{{ str_replace('"', "'", $row->value) }}">{{ str_replace('"', "'", $row->value) }}</option>` Can you try this?

Comment: @Stackerito, You say "But that caused issues because the values I receive from the server may include single or double quotes and it breaks everything.". Why not use htmlspecialchars() and go back to how you did things in PHP?

Comment: you are correct I can do `str_replace` or `htmlspecialchars()` and then `htmlspecialchars_decode()`. Just thought it's better practice to not do that. If that works I can just stick to that

Comment: If this is a common occurence in your application, I would build a templating builder that builds your input elements for you, it shouldn't take much time to create and will save you a lot of time down the line.

Once you have a template for your inputs, you can handle all "sanitizing" logic of quotes etc, on the builder end.